# how to get ManufacturerData from BLE advertisement when scanning for multiple vendors' device

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am scanning for BLE peripherals from 2 different manufacturers. I cannot receive advertisements from both devices without scanning for ALL services, which is unacceptable.

When I configure scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil) I receive both advertisements. However, when I scan for specific services (0xF4FD and 0x0275), I do not receive packets from 0x0275 devices.

- Vendor 0xF4FD advertises the info I need in the CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey.
- Vendor 0x0275 advertises the info I need, but in the CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey.

So 1 vendor is providing data in the ServiceData while the other is using ManufacturerData.

How do I receive both advertisements without resorting to scanning for ALL peripherals?

```
if AppDelegate.cbManager?.state == .poweredOn {

    // 0xF4FD is VendorA device. 0x0275 is VendorB
    // 0xFDF4 alone collects VendorA devices.
    // 0x7502 alone gets nothing
    // both behave the same as 0xFDF4 alone
    // nil gets everything, but kills the battery and collects unwanted devices
    let svcId1 = CBUUID(string: "0xFDF4")
    let svcId2 = CBUUID(string: "0x7502")
    let desiredServices = [svcId2, svcId1]
    cbManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: desiredServices, options: nil)
}
```

... and the receive side...

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    if let key = advertisementData.keys.first(where: { $0.contains(CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey) }), let result = advertisementData[key] {
        print("0xFDF4 peripheral: \(result)")
    }

    if let key = advertisementData.keys.first(where: { $0.contains(CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey) }), let result = advertisementData[key] {
        print("0x7502 peripheral: \(result)")
    }
}
```

... output ...

```
0x7502 peripheral: <750200c6 64ff0b01 3e839fcb f863000e ed91>
0xFDF4 peripheral: {
    FDF4 = <0103fa60 19aaa900 002b51>;
}
0xFDF4 peripheral: {
    FDF4 = <0111f31f 6f8fee00 05368d>;
}
0x7502 peripheral: <750200c6 64ff0b01 103e1cde a0550005 f545>
```

The receive code successfully extracts the data (if/when it gets data).

**EDIT 1**

The call to scanForPeripherals(withServices: "0xFDF4" ) allows me to scan for only for VendorA's service. This correlates to the 5th byte=**0x16** in the Advertising Packet, (called "Service Data-16-bit UUID" in the BLE Spec).

However, VendorB provides the desired info in the Manufacturer Data, which correlates to Advertising Data=**0xff**. ("Manufacturer Specific Data" in the BLE Spec). It seems the 2 parameters are mutually exclusive: either I can get Service Data **or** Manufacturer Data.

- Does that mean that if I want Manufacturer Data, I must scan for ALL services and sift through  all packets from unwanted services??
- Or can I somehow get the Manufacturer Data by subscribing to a Service?

**EDIT 2**

I've learned that Vendor B does not advertise any services. Also, Advertising Data Type=0xFF  corresponds to the iBeacon format. My question now becomes:

- can I scan for Services and iBeacons at the same time?

Comment: The services that you scan for are GATT services. You need to identify the services that your peripherals are advertising that you can scan for to limit your scanning. It seems that FDF4 is one. You need to check the advertised services for the other device.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am in the process of verifying the service I need is being advertised. I have read more and think I see the cause of the problem I have edited my original question accordingly.

Comment: You can use the LightBlue app to see what services are being advertised by a peripheral

Comment: @Paulw11 The device does not advertise any services. It is looking lie a Beacon. I edited my question. Again.